# In rails, how do you set the sprockets config to keep more than 3 copies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, sprockets

How would I go about changing the config for sprockets in rails so it keeps more than 3 old copies of the js/css.

Below is from the sprockets docs about chaging keep, but I'm not sure how to put it in to the rails production environment.

https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails#customize

```
require 'sprockets/rails/task'
Sprockets::Rails::Task.new(Rails.application) do |t|
  t.environment = lambda { Rails.application.assets }
  t.assets = %w( application.js application.css )
  t.keep = 5
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in a file in `lib/tasks`, ending in `.rake`.

So you could for example have `your/app_root/lib/tasks/assets.rake`:

```
require 'sprockets/rails/task'
Sprockets::Rails::Task.new(Rails.application) do |t|
  t.keep = 5
end
```

And that would change the default number of kept files to 5. Alternatively, the rake task also accepts it as an argument, so you could run:

```
rake assets:clean[5]
```

Which would also keep 5 versions of each asset.